# Filtering bad tcp flag packets in CentOS 8

Tags: linux, centos, firewalld

I am using CentOS 8 and want to drop bad tcp flag packets like they were done in CentOS 6 using iptables tcp-flags.

Below are example packet drop done in CentOS 6 using iptables tcp-flags

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP
```

I can see that firewalld service in CentOS 8 does not offer like above except --direct access to underlying iptables/nftables. I don't want to do this.

Is bad/bogus packet drop in CentOS 8 irrelevant? Or is there different way to achieve in CentOS 8 using firewalld?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**: it's redundant to use these rules in any setup using correctly the Netfilter's *conntrack* facility needed for a stateful firewall. As *firewalld* uses it, it's already covered.

The only case where such kind of rules should be used is when the system doesn't use stateful firewalling at all: either not enabling or using *conntrack* at all, or maybe when marking some flows as *untracked*.

I think the most likely cause of regularly seeing this kind of redundant check in today's blogs and rules is that it was inherited from similar rules present in the [*ipchains*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipchains) age with Linux kernel 2.2.x (or at the initial implementation of *conntrack* in Linux 2.4.x which [didn't do such thorough checks](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_proto_tcp.c?v=linux-2.4.22#L140)), where no such stateful firewall facility with extended checks existed and which could make sense then.

More details below.

---

Netfilter's *conntrack* already checks the valid TCP flags while it's tracking TCP packet as seen in [`nf_conntrack_proto_tcp.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_proto_tcp.c#L729):

> ```
> /* table of valid flag combinations - PUSH, ECE and CWR are always valid */
> static const u8 tcp_valid_flags[(TCPHDR_FIN|TCPHDR_SYN|TCPHDR_RST|TCPHDR_ACK|
>                TCPHDR_URG) + 1] =
> {
>   [TCPHDR_SYN]                = 1,
>   [TCPHDR_SYN|TCPHDR_URG]         = 1,
>   [TCPHDR_SYN|TCPHDR_ACK]         = 1,
>   [TCPHDR_RST]                = 1,
>   [TCPHDR_RST|TCPHDR_ACK]         = 1,
>   [TCPHDR_FIN|TCPHDR_ACK]         = 1,
>   [TCPHDR_FIN|TCPHDR_ACK|TCPHDR_URG]  = 1,
>   [TCPHDR_ACK]                = 1,
>   [TCPHDR_ACK|TCPHDR_URG]         = 1,
> };
> ```

Any combination *not* in this table is invalid (that's 23 out of 32 cases. Note for the curious reading the sources that [`NF_ACCEPT=1`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/include/uapi/linux/netfilter.h#L12) and thus [`-NF_ACCEPT`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_proto_tcp.c#L786) is -1 [which means INVALID](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_proto_tcp.c#L801)). This includes OP's three examples `FIN,SYN`, `SYN,RST`, `FIN,RST`. *conntrack* goes beyond this and will also for example [check that the packet is within a valid TCP window](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_proto_tcp.c#L324).

So when *iptables* uses those matches on such bogus packets:

```
-m conntrack --ctstate NEW
-m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED
-m conntrack --ctstate INVALID
```

or the equivalent *nftables* expressions:

```
ct state new
ct state established
ct state invalid
```

only the last: `INVALID`/`invalid`, will match, and should be dropped (with an adequate `-j DROP`/`drop` terminal statement).

Note that CentOS6's [kernel 2.6.18 already filtered those bogus packets](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.18/source/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_proto_tcp.c#L776) (allowing 15/64 cases instead of today's 9/32), so this was already handled simply by dropping such packets with `-m state --state INVALID -j DROP`.

---

Of course *firewalld* uses such matches.

CentOS7's installed *iptables* rules when *firewalld* is running typically include:

```
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
```

CentOS8's installed *nftables* rules when *firewalld* is running with *nftables* backend enabled typically include:

```
# nft list chain inet firewalld filter_INPUT |grep -A2 invalid
        ct state { invalid } drop
        reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited
    }
# nft list chain inet firewalld filter_FORWARD|grep -A2 invalid
        ct state { invalid } drop
        reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited
    }
```

So bogus TCP flags are already handled when using *firewalld*.

---

When not using *firewalld* you should just ensure that you're using this kind of rules (this is an example that most certainly requires more and shouldn't be used as-is, some often needed rules and options are missing) in input and forward paths:

iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
```

(and add any other ACCEPT, DROP or REJECT rules as needed. For a [specific reason](https://serverfault.com/questions/975097/does-nftable-drop-invalid-state-connections-if-i-only-allow-established-and-rela/1031084#1031084), it's important that any REJECT rule is placed *after* the `... INVALID -j DROP` rule)

You could do the same for OUTPUT, but usually one trusts oneself (and crafted RAW packets bypass the firewall anyway).

nftables in `.nft` format example (which has to be completed with specific rules too):

```
table inet mytable {
    chain myinput {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        ct state established accept
        ct state invalid drop
    }

    chain myforward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
        ct state established accept
        ct state invalid drop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 8 uses nftables, so you would express your rules using `nft`.

Maybe the [nftables wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Matching_packet_header_fields) will help you.

Although there is a compatibility layer for iptables in nftable it is not recommended to mix this with native nftables rules.